# MySql Filter Group Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a group query that give me the total count of records available on a LEFT JOIN table. That works fine, however I am trying to add now a filter condition to only show a precise record and the way I am doing it is not working. Does anyone see what I am doing wrong? Thanks so much. Below is the code I have.

```
table1
--------

    t1.abc_uniqueid
    t1.abc_serial
    t1.abc_gender
    t1.abc_fullname
    t1.abc_phone
    t1.abc_bcu_uniqueid
```

2 Record Sample Data:

```
    1
    12344
    'male'
    'john doe'
    '888888888'
    7777

    2
    12345
    'female'
    'jane doe'
    '888888889'
    7777


table2
-------

    lyy_uniqueid
    lyy_abc_uniqueid
    ...
```

2 Record Sample Data:

```
    10
    1
    ...

    11
    2
    ...
```

My GROUP query that works:

```
SELECT
    t1.abc_uniqueid,
    t1.abc_serial As serial,
    t1.abc_gender As gender,
    t1.abc_fullname As fullname,
    t1.abc_phone As phone,
    IFNULL(v.TotalNo, 0) TotalNo   
    FROM 
    table1 t1   LEFT JOIN   ( 
    SELECT lyy_abc_uniqueid, COUNT(*) TotalNo
    FROM table2 v
    GROUP BY lyy_abc_uniqueid   ) v 
    ON v.lyy_abc_uniqueid = t1.abc_uniqueid   
    AND t1.abc_bcu_uniqueid=7777;
```

I want to add a new condition like this:

```
    AND t1.abc_serial=12345;
```

I am able to get the correct result if I use AND t1.abc_bcu_uniqueid=7777 but as soon as I add the new condition, the results are all wrong. For example, if table1 has a row with t1.abc_serial = 1, I want to get the group left join only for that.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this is what you want:

```
SELECT
    t1.abc_uniqueid,
    t1.abc_serial As serial,
    t1.abc_gender As gender,
    t1.abc_fullname As fullname,
    t1.abc_phone As phone,
    IFNULL(v.TotalNo, 0) TotalNo   
    FROM 
    table1 t1   LEFT JOIN   ( 
    SELECT lyy_abc_uniqueid, COUNT(*) TotalNo
    FROM table2 v
    GROUP BY lyy_abc_uniqueid   ) v 
    ON (v.lyy_abc_uniqueid = t1.abc_uniqueid)   
    where t1.abc_bcu_uniqueid=7777 and t1.abc_serial=12345;
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. No, this is exactly what I have and the counter gives the wrong result when I add the second AND (AND t1.abc_serial=12345)

Comment: @carol1287 have you tried with the `where` as i changed.

Comment: MY APOLOGIES! I did not look properly, thank you so much. It works fine now with the WHERE as you suggested. Thanks again and sorry for my oversight.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is because you must add field abc_serial to GROUP BY

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply. abc_serial is only in table1, how could I add abc_serial to a group by if the only group by I have is in table2?